# How to find out if it is possible to contruct a binary matrix with given row and column sums.

Tags: matrices, tomography

How to find out if it is possible to contruct a binary matrix with given row and column sums.

Input :

The first row of input contains two numbers 1≤m,n≤1000, the number of rows and columns of the matrix. The next row contains m numbers 0≤ri≤n – the sum of each row in the matrix. The third row contains n numbers 0≤cj≤m – the sum of each column in the matrix.

Output:

Output “YES” if there exists an m-by-n matrix A, with each element either being 0 or 1. Else "NO".

I tried reading about Tomography algorithms but could not figure out an answer as all the papers related to Tomography algorithm is very complicated.

Can someone please help me..

Comment: see what you can do with $1 \leq m,n \leq 3.$

Comment: Actually, first do $1 \leq m,n \leq 2.$ Do every possible set of inputs, decide what happens for each.

Answer (score 2):

It seems from your description that you don't need to actually compute the matrix, but just insure that the necessary and sufficient conditions exist for one to be computed.  For that, I think that all you'll need is [J. H. Ryser's paper](http://compalg.inf.elte.hu/~tony/Kutatas/Szeged/Ryser-1957.pdf), "Combinatorial properties of matrices of zeros and ones."  You may also find [Richard A. Brualdi's paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379580901056) "Matrices of zeros and ones with fixed row and column vectors" very readable.

Applying those, we first establish some terminology.  As you've already said, the matrix ${\bf A}$ is an $m \times n$ (where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers) matrix of ones and zeros.  Further, we have row and column sum vectors ${\bf R} = (r_1,\dots,r_m$) and ${\bf S}=(s_1,\dots,s_n)$ which are nonnegative integral vectors.  First, it's clear that if there are $\tau$ ones in the matrix ${\bf A}$, then $\displaystyle \tau = \sum_{i=0}^{m}r_i = \sum_{j=0}^{n}s_j$.  If that condition fails, then obviously the answer is "no."

If that succeeds, then following Brualdi, we can define a function to help with the evaluation.  First, let $I \subseteq \left\{ 1,\dots,m \right\}$ and $J \subseteq \left\{1,\dots, n \right\}$.  Define $\displaystyle t(I,J) =|I||J|+\sum_{i \notin I}r_i - \sum_{j \notin J}s_j$. All that remains is to demonstrate that $t(I,J) \ge 0$ for all $I\subseteq\left\{1,\dots,m\right\}$ and $J\subseteq\left\{1,\dots,n\right\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Look up  "network flow" in a linear programming text.

Comment: It would be better to include major points of this algorithm. Otherwise, it's just a "link-only" answer which is not useful for the visitors of this site.